# Any faster way to get pandas dataframe from a nested list

Tags: python, pandas

Below is the working snippet of nested list to dataframe: . But, my actual list is huge. There is 1 M entry and for each entry there is data worth 1000 days. Is there any way to do the same faster?

```
list_sample = [{'name': 'A', 'fame': 0, 'data': {'date':['2021-01-01', '2021-02-01', '2021-03-01'], 
                        'credit_score':[800, 890, 895],
                        'spend':[1500, 25000, 2400], 
                        'average_spend':5000}},
               {'name': 'B', 'fame': 1, 'data': {'date':['2022-01-01', '2022-02-01', '2022-03-01'],
                                   'credit_score':[2800, 390, 8900],
                                   'spend':[15000, 5000, 400], 
                                   'average_spend':3000}}]

df = pd.DataFrame(list_sample)
normalized_data = pd.json_normalize(df['data'])
df = normalized_data.apply(pd.Series.explode).reset_index()
df = df[['date', 'credit_score', 'spend']]
```

Answer (score 3):

couple of things that might help:

1. numpy is usually faster than pandas
2. json_normalize and concat are heavy, try to avoid or use once
3. run speeds of different methods on small sample does not necessarily correlate to run speeds on a bigger sample

saying that, here is my suggestion (apparently it is somewhat faster on current example but, as said, this does not mean too much):

```
values = np.vstack([np.mat((x['data']['date'], x['data']['credit_score'], x['data']['spend'])).T for x in list_sample])
df = pd.DataFrame(values, columns=['date', 'credit_score', 'spend'])
```

or even better:

```
values = np.hstack([(x['data']['date'], x['data']['credit_score'], x['data']['spend']) for x in list_sample])
df = pd.DataFrame(values.T, columns=['date', 'credit_score', 'spend'])
```

Answer (score 3):

For improve performance use `list comprehension` - ouput depends of data, so best test with real data:

```
values = [y for x in list_sample for y in 
          (zip(x['data']['date'], x['data']['credit_score'], x['data']['spend']))]
df = pd.DataFrame(values, columns=['date', 'credit_score', 'spend'])
```

**Sample** 1M:

```
list_sample = [{'name': 'A', 'fame': 0, 'data': {'date':['2021-01-01', '2021-02-01', '2021-03-01'] * 100, 
                        'credit_score':[800, 890, 895] * 100,
                        'spend':[1500, 25000, 2400] * 100, 
                        'average_spend':5000}},
               {'name': 'B', 'fame': 1, 'data': {'date':['2022-01-01', '2022-02-01', '2022-03-01'] * 100,
                                   'credit_score':[2800, 390, 8900] * 100,
                                   'spend':[15000, 5000, 400] * 100, 
                                   'average_spend':3000}}]*1000


In [227]: %%timeit
     ...: values = [y  for x in list_sample for y in (zip(x['data']['date'], x['data']['credit_score'], x['data']['spend']))]
     ...: df = pd.DataFrame(values, columns=['date', 'credit_score', 'spend'])
     ...: 
     ...: 
387 ms ± 4.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [228]: %%timeit
     ...: values = np.vstack([np.mat((x['data']['date'], x['data']['credit_score'], x['data']['spend'])).T for x in list_sample])
     ...: df = pd.DataFrame(values, columns=['date', 'credit_score', 'spend'])
     ...: 
820 ms ± 56.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [229]: %%timeit
     ...: values = np.hstack([(x['data']['date'], x['data']['credit_score'], x['data']['spend']) for x in list_sample])
     ...: df = pd.DataFrame(values.T, columns=['date', 'credit_score', 'spend'])
     ...: 
818 ms ± 109 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Answer (score 2):

**Update**. I now multiplied the initial list by 1M:

```
list_sample = [{'name': 'A', 'fame': 0, 'data': {'date':['2021-01-01', '2021-02-01', '2021-03-01'] * 100, 
                        'credit_score':[800, 890, 895] * 100,
                        'spend':[1500, 25000, 2400] * 100, 
                        'average_spend':5000}},
               {'name': 'B', 'fame': 1, 'data': {'date':['2022-01-01', '2022-02-01', '2022-03-01'] * 100,
                                   'credit_score':[2800, 390, 8900] * 100,
                                   'spend':[15000, 5000, 400] * 100, 
                                   'average_spend':3000}}]*10000
```

And updated my code:

```
%%timeit
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict([x["data"] for x in list_sample])
df2.explode(["date", "credit_score", "spend"])
```

Time:

```
872.9 ms ± 395 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

---

**Update2**: If the list is multiplied like:

```
list_sample = [{'name': 'A', 'fame': 0, 'data': {'date':['2021-01-01', '2021-02-01', '2021-03-01'], 
                        'credit_score':[800, 890, 895],
                        'spend':[1500, 25000, 2400], 
                        'average_spend':5000}},
               {'name': 'B', 'fame': 1, 'data': {'date':['2022-01-01', '2022-02-01', '2022-03-01'],
                                   'credit_score':[2800, 390, 8900],
                                   'spend':[15000, 5000, 400], 
                                   'average_spend':3000}}]*1000000
```

The time will be:

```
4.38 s ± 32.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: it could be faster if you first create list with all `["data"]` and later convert it to `DataFrame`